# why my code works well on small files but not large ones?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming and trying to use python for data analysis. I have some fastq files of paired-end sequencing where each read (data) has a complementary read that is needed for it's analysis.

I have written the following code to select the reads that have a quality score more than 30. It works well on small files (I have tested up to 1 GB) but when I try to use it on real size data, 30 GB, it gives me empty files as results. Can anybody tell me what the problem is? Thanks!

P.S. The average() function mentioned in the code works perfectly. I just skipped it here for the sake of the space.

```
#enter name of the forward source file here
y=open("file1", "r")
lenght=0
for line in y:
    lenght+=1
y.close()
import re
s=0
p=4
#enter name of the forward destination file here
h=open("result1", "w")
#enter name of the reverse destination file here
k=open("result1_complementary", "w")
for turn in range(lenght/4):
    #enter name of the forward source file here
    a=open("file1", "r")
    c=a.readlines()[s:p]
    #enter name of the reverse source file here
    d=open("file1_complementary", "r")
    g=d.readlines()[s:p]
    for line in c:
        #enter the begining of the index line here
        if re.search(r"^@ABC",line):
            #enter the cutting Phred score here
            if average(c[c.index(line)+3])<30:
                del c[0:4]
                del g[0:4]
    for line in g:
        if re.search(r"^@HWI-", line):
            if average(g[g.index(line)+3])<30:
                del g[0:4]
                del c[0:4]

    for line in c:
        h.write(line) 
    for line in g:
        k.write(line)

    s+=4
    p+=4
    a.close()
    d.close()
h.close()
k.close()
```

Comment: You probably do not want to read in a 30GB file without streaming.

Comment: c=a.readlines()[s:p] will read whole file and just take few lines from it. read & process line by line.

Comment: I need to read four lines at the same time, four-line-blocks. How can I do that @iced?

Comment: If I understood well, the "file1" and "file1_complementary" are 30GB files containing millions of lines which makes the 'length' variable huge. With the first loop since you are using 'readlines()' function, you are actually making python to open, read and close two 30GB files hundreds of thousands of times. Although they are getting shortened in each iteration, I guess this process would take a long time to be completed and it require lots of RAM. My guess is the last two lines of your codes had not been executed by python and your program ended before complete execution.

Comment: My suggestion is to  add a line before 'h.close()', like "print('This is to check whether the loops are completed')" so as to check whether the programs gets completely executed by python or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your comments! I used iteration of *readline()* instead of *readlines()[s:p]* and it worked perfectly.