# Code works for a small selection but not the entire database

Tags: python, qgis

I have a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852632/why-my-code-works-well-on-small-files-but-not-large-ones).
I am working on Qgis. To speed things up, I've created a small selection of my map on which I test my code. It works great. Here is the section that poses problem later :

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
iter = layer.getFeatures()
dict = {}

#iterate over features
for feature in iter:

    #print feature.id()
    geom = feature.geometry()
    coord = geom.asPolyline()

### GET FIRST AND LAST POINTS OF POLY + N ORIENTATION###
    # Get Objective Orientation
    d=QgsDistanceArea()
    d.setEllipsoidalMode(True)
    points=geom.asPolyline()
    #second way to get Endpoints
    first = points[0]
    last = points[-1]
    r=d.bearing(first, last)
    b= "NorthOrientation= %s" %(math.degrees(r))
# Assemble Features
    dict[feature.id() ]= [first, last]

### KEY = INTERSECTION, VALUES = COMMONPOINTS###
dictionary = {}
a = dict
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        c = set(a[i]).intersection(set(a[j]))
        if len(c) == 1:
            d = set(a[i]).difference(c)
            c = list(c)[0]
            value = list(d)[0]    #This is where the problem is
            if c in dictionary and value not in dictionary[c]:
                dictionary[c].append(value)
            elif c not in dictionary:
                dictionary.setdefault(c, [])
                dictionary[c].append(value)

        else: pass

print dictionary
```

This code works for the 10 polylines of my small selection (which I've stored in a seperate shapefile). But when I try to run it though the 40 000 lines of my original database, I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/16116/appdata/local/temp/tmp96wd24.py", line 47, in <module>
    value = list(d)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

A few things:
This code stems from a first question that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414482/how-do-i-extract-part-of-a-tuple-thats-duplicate-as-key-to-a-dictionary-and-ha/37417577#37417577). I'm still pretty new to python so to be honest I have a hard time understanding how this exact part of the code works, but I know it does (at least for the small dataset).

The small "test selection"'s structure is identical to the entire database. Only the length has changed.

If anyone has had the same experience or knows why this problem occures, I would be very greatful for any indications.

Comment: Not really an answer but it seems that your `d` variable is empty (so there wasn't anything returned by `set(a[i]).difference(c)`. Depending on if you think it can happen, you can handle this with something like `if not d: # do something..` or `if len(d) == 0:`. Also for the clarity of your code you should avoid to override builtins objects with variable name (as you are doing with `dict` for example).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am going to restructure my code to set what I can in classes. "if not d:" lets me run though the entire code, but I'm not sure yet what impact this will have on my results so I'm going to leave this question open for now.